# REST php Rewrite Rules

Tags: php, xml, json, rest, mod-rewrite

I try to make a rest-api to Post / Put / Get and Delete Guitars.

Now i already can use POST / GET and DELETE .. and i kinda gonna wrestle with PUT the next few days.

Now i have allready rewritten my .htacces to get an format as XML or JSON if i put .json or .xml behind my URI.

In my JSON i have putten a self-link type and the href is the link with the id attached to it.

For some reason if i click on the links i just keep getting the Summary Page with ALL ID's. I don't know what i am doing wrong :S

.htacces file

```
    RewriteEngine on
#Get Whole Guitar Summary
RewriteRule ^guitars$ service.php?type=json [QSA]
RewriteRule ^guitars.json$ service.php?type=json [QSA]
RewriteRule ^guitars.xml$ service.php?type=xml [QSA]


#Only Get Guitar by ID
RewriteRule ^guitars/([0-9]*)$ service.php?id=$1&type=json 
RewriteRule ^guitars/([0-9]*).json$ service.php?id=$1&type=json 
RewriteRule ^guitars/([0-9]*).xml$ service.php?id=$1&type=xml
```

This is my "GET" case in my Service.php

```
case "GET":
 //GET METHODE
 $guitars = 'SELECT * FROM gitaren';
 $GuitarSummary = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $guitars);


//Representaties instellen
if($_GET['type'] == 'json'){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($GuitarSummary)){
        $jsonArray[] = array(
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "brand" => $row['brand'],
            "model" => $row['model'],
            "strings" => $row['strings'],
            "price" => $row['price'],
            "available" => $row['available'],
            "link" => array(
                'rel' => 'self',
                'href' => 'http://localhost/imp6-webservices/eindopdracht/gitaren/'.$row['id']
            )
        );
    }
        echo json_encode($jsonArray);
}
else {
header ('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8'?>";
    echo "<gitaren>";
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($GuitarSummary)){
        echo "<gitaar>";
        echo "<id>".$row['id']."</id>";
        echo "<brand>".$row['brand']."</brand>";
        echo "<model>".$row['model']."</model>";
        echo "<strings>".$row['strings']."</strings>";
        echo "<price>".$row['price']."</price>";
        echo "<available>".$row['available']."</available>";
        echo "</gitaar>";
    }
    echo "</gitaren>";
}


//Zoekqueries voor POSTman overzicht
if(isset($_GET['brand']))
{
    $brand =  $_GET['brand'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM gitaren WHERE brand = '$brand'  ";
}
    if (isset($_GET['model']))
    {
        $model = $_GET['model'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM gitaren WHERE model = '$model'  ";
    }
    if (isset($_GET['strings']))
    {
        $strings = $_GET['strings'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM gitaren WHERE strings = '$strings'  ";
    }
    if (isset($_GET['price']))
    {
        $price = $_GET['price'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM gitaren WHERE price = '$price'  ";
    }
    if (isset($_GET['available']))
    {
        $available = $_GET['available'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM gitaren WHERE available = '$available'  ";
    }
    break;
```

Please dont mind the Dutch commentary putted in and the XML colomns in Dutch.

I hope you guys can help me out.

Kind Regards,

Jay!

Comment: If you would like to be RESTy, use `Accept` header in your request to define response content format, do not use `.xml` or `.json`. And I would recommend setting `Content-type` to `application/xml` and `application/json` instead of `text/*`.

Comment: To solve your "returning just IDs" do some debugging, to see what you retrieve from database and what is your JSON/XML response composed of. Which "links" you are clicking on, please post the whole URL?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to send the accept header.. is it like 
     header `('Accept : application/xml')`???

The URI i try to link on is 

http://localhost/rest/guitars/3 but still i get a fully page... I tried queries that if i look for a certain query (http://localhost/rest/guitars?brand=Gibson i still can't get it to work

Comment: Exactly, add to your header `Accept: application/xml`. If you are getting full page, do not echo your result, use something like `die(json_encode($json_array)` which will cause the PHP script to stop and return all the outputs performed before this statement. Which should be your requested behaviour - collect and return data.